# react-native:react-navigation can't get simple transition working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using a StackNavigator from react-navigation. I want a simple card slide animation to occur in my component. The current transition is one where the second screen slides up from the bottom. I want the standard slide effect(which is supposed to be the default in the first place).

The StackNavigator is created as follows:

```
const Stack = StackNavigator(
  {
    Phone: {
      screen: Phone,
    },
    Code: {
      screen: Code
    }
  },
{
  mode: 'card',
  headerMode: 'none',
  cardStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "transperent"
  }
});
```

And this is the navigationOptions I used in the components:

```
static navigationOptions = {
header: {
  visible: false,
}
```

Comment: Can you update the question to include how you're calling the `navigate` function to transition from the phone screen to the code screen?

Comment: onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Code')}

Comment: Are you testing on iOS or Android?  On iOS, the standard is to slide in form the right side.  I just tested your code and it slides in from the right on my iPhone.  My guess is that you are testing on Android, which has a different default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I created a little snack, with the expo app, of your code.  If you are developing on iOS, it will slide in from the right.

https://snack.expo.io/HkKhDNJ4W

Comment: Thanks for testing. Any idea how to change it? I tried setting mode but that did nothing

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the intended slide effect is.  You said you want 'the standard slide effect', but I'm not sure what you mean by that.  Do you mean that you want it to slide in from the right?

Comment: Yes. I already found the issue.  The version of react-navigation I pulled did not have transitionConfig defined on the CardStack component. Honestly I wonder why the standard navigator was dropped so soon